Hypergeometric distributions - A specific sequence of marbles.
Edit: It seems the question was simply too ambiguous, and it assumed it was with replacement so its not hypergeometric: (https://i.imgur.com/xwGU1zZ.png)
I came across a question that asked: If you have 100 marbles, 50 red and 50 green, and you are going to draw 7 marbles, what is the probability you obtain the exact sequence: R G R G G R G.
The solution claimed 1/2^7, because each action is independent from the other. As I understand, the probability of getting a green marble on say the 5th draw, before I draw any marbles, is going to be 50% because I do not know what the previous draws are yet.
Why can I not calculate this probability using conditional probabilities? If we simplify the problem: What is the probability I obtain the exact sequence: R G
Then by extension the answer is 1/4.
This can only happen in one way: I draw the first marble and it is red, and then I draw the second marble and it is green. But this gives me 50/100 * 50/99. What am I missing for this to equal 1/4? I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on.
Edit: corrected a typo, previously wrote 50/100 * 49/99~

Your title says hypergeometric distribution. If that is so, $\frac1{2^7}$ is incorrect.

If marbles are drawn without replacement, the quoted solution is incorrect.

Please clarify whether the marbles are drawn with or without replacement.

I regenerated the question (and solution), its black/white marbles but the same idea. I assumed it was without replacement, maybe I just misunderstood the question: https://i.imgur.com/xwGU1zZ.png

The question you quote is defective (incompletely specified) because it doesn't say whether the draws are with or without replacement.

The answer with replacement is $\frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12$ while without replacement it is $\frac{50}{100} \times \frac{50}{99} \times \frac{49}{98} \times \frac{49}{97} \times \frac{48}{96} \times \frac{48}{95} \times \frac{47}{94}$ which is marginally larger. Your image of the question does not clarify which is intended, but the suggested answer is correct only if the draw is with replacement.
